# Minimizing function with summation

Tags: calculus, optimization, random-variables, discrete-optimization

Suppose that $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n$ are random variables with progressively decreasing bias. We want to solve for $d$ which is the number of random variables we leave out. How and can I find a closed form solution to this problem?

Let function $\hat{f} : \{0,1,\dots,n\} \to \Bbb R$ be defined by

$$ \hat{f}(d) := \frac1{n-d} \sum_{i=d+1}^n Y_i $$

Let

$$ \mbox{MSER} := \frac{1}{(n-d)^2} \sum_{i=d+1}^n \left( Y_i - \hat{f}(d) \right)^2 $$

How do I minimize MSER w.r.t. to $d$?

---

I know that I need to take the first derivative of MSER w.r.t. to $d$,but that's as far as I've gotten.

Comment: Could we assume that the summation is just a constant independent of $d$? I am not sure! Also are all values of Y positive? Is $n$ positive? Is $f(d)$ continuous?

Comment: oh wait, we can't right because d is the lower part of the summation right? How would I deal with it if it isn't?

Comment: Looking at the expression of $\frac{S}{1-d}$, it tends to touch zero as d gets large. an gets very large as d approaches zero. That is assuming the summation is positive.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, thank you for your patience. I finally understand where I am going wrong in my explanation. I want to minimize the mean squared error between my estimate and the actuals wrt to d. Say g(d) is the mean squared error. Let $g(d) = \frac{1}{n-d} (\frac{1}{n-d} \sum_{i=d+1}^n (Y_i - \hat{f_d})^2)$

where $ \hat{f_d} = \sum_{i=d+1}^n Y_i$

Comment: I would use $k$ instead of $d$.  Letters like $k$, $m$, $n$ and $p$ are often used for integers and sticking to conventions is beneficial

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo gotcha! Does this problem make sense now?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I have updated it. I am trying to find what value of d minimizes this MSER function.

Comment: Note that $\hat f$ should be a function of the $Y_i$ too.  Also, your MSER is also a random variable.  To remove the stochasticity, you can take the expected value of the right-hand side, which should give your the "energy / power of the noise" (think of the heat dissipated by a resistor)

Comment: Yes, $\hat{f}$ is a function of $Y_i$. Where would I go after taking the expected value though? I know that the mean squared error is equal to the $bias^2 + variance$

Comment: @ChessGuy You would have to provide the means and variances of the $Y_i$, mention if they are independent, etc.  Then, compute the MSER in terms of $d$ and such means and variances.  I strongly recommend that you use $k$ instead of $d$, as $d$ is a horrible name for an integer variable.  I would recommend that you build a vector $\bf Y$ via stacking the $Y_i$.  Try to write the MSER in terms of $\bf Y$, say, using matrices.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I know that the expectation of $\hat{f} = f$, $Y_i$ is independent and that for the variance I can just use $\sigma$. How do I follow this up and get the optimal k? If you have any resources or examples that can fill in the gaps in my knowledge, that would be great

Comment: @ChessGuy Start by updating the MSER

Comment: @ChessGuy You forgot to mention what the distribution of the $Y_i$ is

Comment: @ChessGuy Why aren't you updating the question? Have you quit?